# convert jquery.submit to ajax submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I can't seem to figure out how to submit a form from the jquery ui button function using Ajax.

Here's my script that submits the form via the conventional way

```
        $('#contact-form').dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                Ok: function () {
                    $('form#contactUs').submit();
                    $(this).dialog('destroy');
                }
            }
        });

        $('#contact-us').click(function () {
            $('#contact-form').dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

and here's my form

```
<div id="contact-form" class="hidden" title="Online Request Form">
    <form action="/Main/Contact/contactUs" method="post">            
        <div>
            <label for="Name">Name</label><br />
            <input name="Name" /><br />
            <label for="PhoneNumber">Phone Number</label><br />
            <input name="PhoneNumber" /><br />
            <label for="EmailAddress">Email Address</label><br />
            <input name="EmailAddress" /><br />
            <label for="Question">Question or Comment</label><br />
            <textarea name="Question"></textarea><br />
            <label for="Security">What color is an orange?</label><br />
            <input name="Security" />
            <noscript>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ok" />
            </noscript>
        </div>
    </form>    
</div>
```

How can I change this up to submit the link via Ajax so that I can display a success message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I found

```
<div id="contact-form" class="hidden" title="Online Request Form">
    @Using (Ajax.BeginForm("Contact", "Main",
                          Nothing,
                          New AjaxOptions With {.UpdateTargetId = "", .HttpMethod = "post"},
                          New With {.id = "contactUs"}))
        @<div>
            <label for="Name">Name</label><br />
            <input name="Name" /><br />
            <label for="Phone">Phone Number</label><br />
            <input name="Phone" /><br />
            <label for="Email">Email Address</label><br />
            <input name="Email" /><br />
            <label for="Question">Question or Comment</label><br />
            <textarea name="Question"></textarea><br />
            <label for="Security">What color is an orange?</label><br />
            <input name="Security" />
            <noscript>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ok" />
            </noscript>
        </div>
    End Using
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#contact-form').dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                Ok: function () {
                    $('form#contactUs').trigger('submit');
                    $(this).submit();
                }
            }
        });

        $('#contact-us').click(function () {
            $('#contact-form').dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

This is probably sufficient:

```
$("#contact-form form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post( $(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), 
                function(resp) {
                    if(resp == "success") {
                        alert('Submission was successful');
                    } else {
                        // something else
                    }
                }
    });              
});
```

Brief explanation:

- Bind an onsubmit event handler to the contact form. Prevent the 'normal' submit.
- Serialize the form, and send the result to the form's action.
- Evaluate the response, and somehow display a message.

Further reading:

- http://docs.jquery.com/Post
- http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/
- http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Does the data serialization work when posting a strongly typed view? `Function Contact(ByVal contactForm As Models.ContactForm) As ActionResult`

Comment: I'm not an asp.net guy, but it be serialize into a query string and look like this: 'foo=bar&var=something'. Take a look at: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Thank you for your direction. I've +1'ed your answer, but I've gone a different direction. See my answer.